# How do I evaluate a environment variable using Go's os/exec

Tags: go

How do I get Go to evaluate the $PATH variable. I currently just prints
"$PATH"

I have the following code

```
package main

import (
        "fmt"
        "log"
        "os/exec"
)

func main() {
        out, err := exec.Command("echo","$PATH").Output()
        if err != nil {
                log.Fatal(err)
        }
        fmt.Printf("%s\n",out)
}
```

Comment: If you want to get the path, [`os.Getenv("PATH")`](http://golang.org/pkg/os/#Getenv). If you want to do shell substitution on a commands, maybe pass the whole command to a shell (and be very sure you're not passing along untrusted user input).

Comment: check this SO question/answer - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49001114/shell-expansion-command-substitution-in-golang

Answer (score 5):

You need to use `os.Getenv("PATH")`

```
package main

import (
  "fmt"
  "log"
  "os/exec"
  "os"
)

func main() {
  out, err := exec.Command("echo",os.Getenv("PATH")).Output()
  if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
  }
  fmt.Printf("%s\n",out)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this -

```
CommandToRun = os.ExpandEnv(os.Getenv("CommandToRun"))
```

This will read `CommandToRun` and expand if there are any env vars in it.

[Play example](https://play.golang.org/p/5cBNPFhpl4e)