# Shell Expansion (Command substitution) in Golang

Tags: shell, go, command-substitution

Go has the support for **variable expansion**, for example:

> os.ExpandEnv("test-**${USER}**")`
>
> >> "test-MyName"

But is there a way of expanding **executables**, as the way the shell behaves?

Something like

> os.ExpandExecutable("test-**$(date +%H:%M)**")
>
> >> "test-18:20"

I cannot find an equivalent method for this, is there an elegant way of doing this instead of manually extracting the placeholders out, executing and then replacing them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no built in function for this, but you can write a function and pass it to `os.Expand()`.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "os/exec"
    "strings"
)

func RunProgram(program string) string {
    a := strings.Split(program, " ")
    out, err := exec.Command(a[0], a[1:]...).Output()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    return string(out)
}
```

// You then call it as:

```
func main() {
    s := os.Expand("test-${date +%H:%M}", RunProgram)
    fmt.Print(s)
}
```

This outputs:

```
test-13:09
```

Note that `os.Expand()` expects curly braces, i.e. `${command args args args}`.